# setFirstName() is not a function, and returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I am working on a full stack application using react, and I am creating a website that adds a user to the database, I am using a class based component:

**PersonalDetails.js**

```jsx
import styles from "../styles/style.module.css";
import { Component } from "react";

class PersonalDetails extends Component {
  constructor({
    firstName,
    setFirstName,
    lastName,
    setLastName,
    username,
    setUsername,
    mobile,
    setMobile,
    email,
    setEmail,
    preferedLanguage,
    setPreferedLanguage,
  }) {
    super({
      firstName,
      setFirstName,
      lastName,
      setLastName,
      username,
      setUsername,
      mobile,
      setMobile,
      email,
      setEmail,
      preferedLanguage,
      setPreferedLanguage,
    });
  }

  handleFnameChange = (event) => {
    this.props.setFirstName(event.target.value);
    console.log(this.props.setFirstName);
    console.log(this.firstName);
  };

  handleLnameChange = (event) => {
    this.setLastName(event.target.value);
  };

  handleUnameChange = (event) => {
    this.setUserName(event.target.value);
  };

  handleMobileChange = (event) => {
    this.setMobile(event.target.value);
  };

  handleEmailChange = (event) => {
    this.setEmail(event.target.value);
  };

  handleLanguageChange = (event) => {
    this.setPreferedLanguage(event.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={styles.sectionTitle}>
          <h3>Personal Details</h3>
          <hr></hr>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.doubleContainer}>
          <div className={styles.inputlabelContainer}>
            <label for="fname" className={styles.personalDetailsLabel}>
              First Name
              <span className={styles.star}>*</span>
            </label>
            <input
              id="fname"
              value={this.firstName}
              onChange={this.handleFnameChange}
              className={styles.personalDetailsInput}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter First Name"
              required
            ></input>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.inputlabelContainer}>
            <label for="lname" className={styles.personalDetailsLabel}>
              Last Name
              <span className={styles.star}>*</span>
            </label>
            <input
              id="lname"
              value={this.lastName}
              onChange={this.handleLnameChange}
              className={styles.personalDetailsInput}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter Last Name"
              required
            ></input>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.doubleContainer}>
          <div className={styles.inputlabelContainer}>
            <label for="uname" className={styles.personalDetailsLabel}>
              User Name
              <span className={styles.star}>*</span>
            </label>
            <input
              id="uname"
              value={this.username}
              onChange={this.handleUnameChange}
              className={styles.personalDetailsInput}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter User Name"
              required
            ></input>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.inputlabelContainer}>
            <label for="mobilenb" className={styles.personalDetailsLabel}>
              Mobile Number
              <span className={styles.star}>*</span>
            </label>
            <input
              id="mobilenb"
              value={this.mobile}
              onChange={this.handleMobileChange}
              className={styles.personalDetailsInput}
              type="tel"
              placeholder="Enter Mobile Number"
              required
            ></input>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.doubleContainer}>
          <div className={styles.inputlabelContainer}>
            <label for="email" className={styles.personalDetailsLabel}>
              Email
              <span className={styles.star}>*</span>
            </label>
            <input
              id="email"
              value={this.email}
              onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
              className={styles.personalDetailsInput}
              type="email"
              placeholder="Enter Email Address"
              required
            ></input>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.inputlabelContainer}>
            <label for="piflanguage" className={styles.personalDetailsLabel}>
              Preferred Interface Language
              <span className={styles.star}>*</span>
            </label>
            <select
              id="piflanguage"
              value={this.preferedLanguage}
              onChange={this.handleLanguageChange}
              className={styles.inputlabelContainer}
            >
              <option value="English">English</option>
              <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>
              <option value="French">French</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default PersonalDetails;
```

**Explanation:**

When I use `this.setFirstName` in the `handleFnameChange()` I get the error that `this.setFirstName()` is not a function, and when I use `this.props.setFirstName()` I get the result of firstName as undefined, the same for all other functions(setLastName, setMobile...)

**What's the problem?**

Comment: As `setFirstName` is the props that you are passing from the parent component, the correct way to use it is by `this.props.setFirstName`. As for the firstName being undefined, it is because the state updates in react are not synchronous, you can do `console.log(this.props)` in the render method to see the difference if it is changing or not.

Comment: I used this.props on all of them but it's still returning empty values I honestly don't know what to do

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox for this?